# Pandas read csv no longer gives error when there is a change in column size

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv with 100 columns at the start.

When it gets to line 2137 it changes to 105 columns and then continues until 300092.

When I have read this before it has giving me a parser error which I have been writing code to deal with the file.

Now when I try to open the file the error no longer happens and makes 5 empty columns at the end until line 2137

In:

```
df = pd.read_csv(files, header=1, sep=',', skiprows=0, engine='python', on_bad_lines = 'error')
```

Out:

```
                 Date      Time  ... Unnamed: 103       Unnamed: 104
0      14/09/2021  13:49:46  ...          NaN                NaN
1      14/09/2021  13:49:48  ...          NaN                NaN
2      14/09/2021  13:49:50  ...          NaN                NaN
3      14/09/2021  13:49:52  ...          NaN                NaN
4      14/09/2021  13:49:54  ...          NaN                NaN
...           ...       ...  ...          ...                ...
30085  15/09/2021  06:27:25  ...            5  No Alarms Present
30086  15/09/2021  06:27:27  ...            5  No Alarms Present
30087  15/09/2021  06:27:29  ...            5  No Alarms Present
30088  15/09/2021  06:27:31  ...            5  No Alarms Present
30089  15/09/2021  06:27:33  ...            5  No Alarms Present
```

How do I get the error to come back as I need to split the file and deal with each part separately as the data shifts?
I have tried a few different things and done searches but haven't found anything.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of pandas is used?

Comment: Version is 1.5.2, last time i tried this is the latest it wanted to install

Comment: I am not able to replicate. Your code works in 1.5.3 (i.e. latest at the moment). I also downgraded to 1.5.2 and again, not able to replicate. Tested on windows and python 3.11.0. I get `pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3` (as I would expect given my test file)

Comment: I have windows, python 3.11.1 and pandas 1.5.2. What I don't understand is that I have been getting the error all week and now it no longer appears. I guess just remove and reinstall pandas

Comment: If no change in the setup - check very carefully the file. It looks almost certain there is something in the data format you overlook. Test with different file that worked in the past. Also check again your code

Comment: So if the file is local then I get no error. But if the file is put somewhere else like on a server then it gives me the error.
Even though the files are identical